# to return a 404 response from a middleware in nextjs

Tags: next.js

In a nextjs app, I am checking in middleware for some checks and then if it fails, I want to return a 404 response from middleware.

How do I return a 404 response from middleware in nextjs ?

I did this

```
if(req.nextUrl.pathname != "/" && req.nextUrl.locale === 'default')
    {
        return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(`/not-found`, req.url));
    }
```

But I am not sure if rewrite is the correct way.

I was looking for a simple way to return a 404 page when locale is default (the url doesn't have local code) on all pages except homepage.

Comment: Using `redirect`/`rewrite` is the right way to do that with the new middleware. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-upgrade-guide#no-response-body.